# Heatmaps with repeating X and Y values in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, heatmap

So, I have a set of 3 lists of data, all with a length of 105 items.  The first list is a list of 21 temperature values, of which there are 5 sets.  The second list is made up of Kzz values, which there are 5 of, corresponding to each of the sets of temperature values. The third list is molecular abundances, all of which are unique.  While the temperature and Kzz values do repeat, they never repeat in tandem in relation to the molecular abundance values, acting more like categories than anything else.  Temperature and Kzz do have some relation to the molecular abundance, but as this data is empirical, the exact relationship isn't yet known.

My intent was to plot these three lists in a heat map, where the x and y coordinates would be the temperature and Kzz values, and the color would be determined by the molecular abundance value.

However, I've not been able to.  My first attempt was to insert each list into a dataframe to then plot it using Seaborn's heatmap function (after transforming the dataframe into a pivot table using df.pivot() ), but when I tried to transform it, pandas through an error due to their being repeated y coordinate values:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Without turning the dataframe into a pivot table, however, the heatmaps just ended up being an unintelligible mess.

I then tried using matplotlib's contour function, but that didn't work because the molecular abundances are 1D, and contour needs its z values in the form of a 2D array. Trying plt.pcolor(temperatures,kzz values, molecular abundances) yields the error

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Matplotlib's imshow *did* work, but only showed two colors, which didn't result in a particularly useful plot.

What's going to be the best way to get this data plotted in a heat-map-like form? Or an otherwise useful form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code, with extensive comments, shows how such a heatmap can be drawn:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import random

# suppose you have a list of 5 times 21 temperatures
temp = [i for i in range(10, 31)] * 5
# suppose you have 5 Kzz, each one for  21 temperatures
Kzz = [j for i in range(10, 31) for j in range(2, 12, 2)]
# suppose you have 105 abundances, corresponding to the temperature-Kzz pairs
abundances = [random.random() for _ in range(len(temp))]

# the easiest to work with is to convert the lists to numpy arrays
#  to make them 2D, with a dimension of 5x21, reshape() can be used
temp = np.array(temp).reshape(5, 21)
Kzz = np.array(Kzz).reshape(5, 21)
abundances = np.array(abundances).reshape(5, 21)

# to draw a heatmap, the principal ingredient are the abundances having the correct 2D shape;
# to tell seaborn what the x and y axes mean, a list of 21 temperatures can be given as xticklabels
#   and 5 Kzz values as yticklabels
sns.heatmap(abundances, xticklabels=temp[0, :], yticklabels=Kzz[:, 0], cmap='inferno')
plt.xlabel('temperature')
plt.ylabel('Kzz')
plt.title('molecular abundances')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: You could use the same data to create a scatter plot. The scatter plot helps to show the given data and might give additional insight when the contourplot doesn't give the expected result.

```py
plt.scatter(temp, Kzz, c=abundances, cmap='inferno')
```